# Problem on Superset dashboard: Unexpected error 504

Tags: apache-superset

I have Apache superset version 1.2.0 in docker (Ubuntu 18.04), Frequently I am getting a 504 error on one of the dashboard,
I have added SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_TIMEOUT = 300 in superset_config.py,
Still I am getting the same issue. Any suggestion please.

Error Message:

```
<html> <head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head> <body> <center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center> </body> </html> <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page --> <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page --> <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page --> <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page --> <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page --> <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

Comment: were you able to find some solution?

Answer (score 0):

Long running query(mins - hours) requires Celery workers since web request timeouts are within 30-60 seconds.

Comment: Is there a way to configure timeout? I have the same issue, I have already added the timeout flags in the superset_config.py file in the docker/pythonpath_dev folder but unfortunately no luck.